# Squealing coming from laptop power supply?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, hp-pavilion

I have an HP Pavilion dv7-6135dx. This morning, the power supply/AC adapter started making squealing noises for a few seconds at a time.

I had it plugged in during a storm that happened while I was sleeping. As soon as I got up and realized, I put it in a surge protector. As I type this, it seems to have stopped for the moment, but it was going on and off almost constantly a couple of minutes ago.

I'm assuming this means I need to replace the supply, but not sure if it actually means anything at all.

Running Ubuntu 15.04, it that's relevant.

EDIT: I should also mention that I had the laptop powering 4 usb devices (Keyboard, mouse, gaming controllers) for several hours yesterday. Again, don't know if this is relevant.

EDIT 2: As I start to use the laptop, I'm noticing that it seems to squeak a little bit when I pick up the mouse or start typing.

Comment: If the noise has stopped I'd let it go until it recurs.  (Though the power bricks are generally reasonably cheap.  And, forewarned, you have the time to get an authentic one, vs a cheap knockoff that doesn't really meet specs.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal for some AC adapters right out of the box (old dells commonly had this problem) and sometimes it occurs only after extensive use. No harm is being done as of now. If it bothers you too much or if it starts to take to long to charge or no change at all, just replace it. You can pick these up off eBay for pretty cheap. Just make sure you look through the reviews to buy from a reputable source.